# Android layout problem with EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am designing an android user interface I am facing some problem in designing it can anybody guide me.

[image]

I need UI same as the above where there is not space between 2 EditText.

Regards

Altaf

Comment: I do not understand your question. Can you please elaborate? The "Email" and "Password" entries are EditText Views and you wish to have it so they have no space between them? Or do you wish to have them show up like they do in the image?

Comment: Can you add what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Vinay I want to layout just like image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change its background. The default Android `EditText` has padding because of its background.

[image: Focused EditText]

Here's the `EditText`'s background xml description:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/editbox_background_focus_yellow"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/editbox_background_normal"/>
</selector>
```

Just provide image for these states, create a similar drawable xml file in your project and you'll be able to change how `EditText`s look like.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the background to either your own drawable or a color.  Try setting the `background` of each EditText to #FFFFFFFF, and make sure there are no margins set. That will cause them to be flush next to each other.

For the grey separator between the 2, add a `View` (just plain `View`) with layout_height of 1dp and layout_width of fill_parent between the two EditTexts.  Then set the background color of that to #FF868686.